# not able to access angular2 app from docker container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-machine, angular-cli

I created a docker container using official node image.

```
docker pull node
```

then I created an angular 2 app using angular-cli.

```
ng new docker-demo
```

then I ran my docker container from the directory of my angular2 app using following command:

```
cd docker-demo
```

&  then inside the directory :

```
docker run -p 8080:4200 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

where pwd stands for directory of my angular2 app.

now in my console I can see my angular2 app getting bundled & running just like it runs on my local machine.

but when I try to access it from my browser using ip of my docker-machine :

```
http://192.168.99.100:8080/
```

it doesn't work.

PS: angular2 app works perfectly fine in my local system.

is there any extra configuration required?

any inputs?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you first start your angular app container and then try to test if app is really working by `exec`uting curl: `docker exec -it <angular app container id> curl localhost:4200`. Does it work?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. Was able to fix it using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` as the starting command for my container. It is important to remember exposing the right ports at build time. Make sure you use `EXPOSE 4200` or any other port you want to expose your app in your Dockerfile. 4200 is the default for Angular2/4 apps, so most of the time is the best choice.

If you're using Docker compose, the same thing. Remember to expose the port and use the appropriate arguments in the ng serve command. Hope it helps you and any other fellow captain struggling with the same problem.

Comment: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 did the trick. Even if you are EXPOSE-ing the port, angular itself would refuse to host outside localhost, unless explicitly stated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your docker command should be like this:

```
docker run --rm --name my-container -it -p 8080:4200 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

- --rm -> will remove you container when you stop it
- -it -> will folow log output
- --name -> give a name for your container

You need **-it** if you want follow the log or **-d** if you dont wana folow the log output.

I recomment to use **--name your-container-name** to make easy to remove/stop/start your container.

To check the status of you container:

```
docker ps -a
```

Where -a will show all containers, inclusive stoped containers.

See more here: [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: tried this..but still not able to access my angular2 app from browser

Comment: the **docker ps -a** show your container with status "Up ..." ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the port as per the [image installation guide](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/):

Create a Dockerfile in your Node.js app project

```
FROM node:4-onbuild
# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 8888
```

You can then build and run the Docker image:

```
$ docker build -t my-nodejs-app .
$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app my-nodejs-app
```

So in your case:

```
> ng new docker-demo
> cd docker-demo
> echo "FROM node:6.6.0-wheezy
EXPOSE 4200" > Dockerfile
> docker build -t my-nodejs-app .
> docker run --rm --name docker-demo -p 8080:4200 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" my-nodejs-app npm start
```

You app should be accessible on `127.0.0.1:8080` (replace 127.0.0.1 with relevant docker ip).

Comment: Exposing port through Dockerfile is not necessary. One can always publish any ports on container using `docker run -p <host port>:<container port>`.