# Angular 5 application not accessbile over network or outside the docker

Tags: angular, docker

I have a working Angular 5 app which I am struggling to make working with docker-compose.

Though similar kind of problem has been faced by many people but suggested solution does not work for me:

[Access Angular app running inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633244/access-angular-app-running-inside-docker-container)

[Cannot access nodejs app on browser at localhost:4200 (docker run -p 4200:4200 ....)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285130/cannot-access-nodejs-app-on-browser-at-localhost4200-docker-run-p-42004200)

[nodejs app doesn't connect to localhost when running within a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285857/nodejs-app-doesnt-connect-to-localhost-when-running-within-a-docker-container/48286174#48286174)

[ng serve not working in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778868/ng-serve-not-working-in-docker-container)

[not able to access angular2 app from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551135/not-able-to-access-angular2-app-from-docker-container)

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  webui-ng:
     container_name: bcrm-webui-ng
     build: ./webui-angular   
     ports: 
      - 4200:4200
```

Below is the Docker file which is located under ./webui-angular.

```
FROM node:9.6.1

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Expose API port to the outside
EXPOSE 4200

# Launch application
#CMD ["npm","run ng serve"]
#CMD ["npm", "run", "ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
#CMD ["npm", "run", "ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "ng", "serve", "--open", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
CMD npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Please note that all the commands commented on last lines don't work. That is I always get "The connection was reset" error in Firefox when I open http://localhost:4200

Here is command line output

```
bcrm-webui-ng | 
bcrm-webui-ng | > Xyz@0.1.0 ng /usr/src/app
bcrm-webui-ng | > ng "serve" "0.0.0.0"
bcrm-webui-ng | 
bcrm-webui-ng | ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
bcrm-webui-ng | Date: 2018-09-24T14:03:38.509Z                                                           
bcrm-webui-ng | Hash: 4ac012def02ed7e0a08a
bcrm-webui-ng | Time: 19848ms
bcrm-webui-ng | chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
bcrm-webui-ng | chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 1.81 MB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
bcrm-webui-ng | chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 221 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
bcrm-webui-ng | chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 28.2 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
bcrm-webui-ng | chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.25 MB [initial] [rendered]
bcrm-webui-ng | 
bcrm-webui-ng | webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: did you face this problem the very first time you successfully executed docker compose? or is it a subsequent issue?

Comment: Its a subsequent issue. I tried many many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigating, I came to know that problem is not at docker end but instead following command does not work

```
npm run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

But only running through works well.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker is not getting the `port` address it got the first time. This happens when you `run` instead of `start` the docker each time. It just ties the `4200` port with the first container(which you will see if you run a `docker ps -a`).

Solution is to

- remove your earlier container before you run docker compose
- doing a docker inspect each time you do the docker compose
- set a name to your container so your docker compose will warn you from creating duplicate containers. it can be done using `--name` in the docker run command.

you may choose one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) and then ran again the sudo docker-compose up --build. Now the sudo docker ps gives following output which shows that the image is created again but still I am facing the same issue. CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b0a265094568        source_webui-ng     "/bin/sh -c 'npm run…"   About a minute ago   Up 58 seconds       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp   bcrm-webui-ng

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-running-host-but-not-accessible/44082/7 the same issue as yours, do a `docker inspect` on the container (using `id` or `name`) and see which ip it is currently running on. if you want to tie your docker with an ip permanently you need pipeworks https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework. But you need to name your container before doing that because the pipeworks command needs a name.